# iproute rt_table and mark not working on linux

Tags: linux, iptables, iproute2

I have this configuration which comes from official and unofficial guides and questions readings here and a lot of failed tests.
CentOS 7 and Ubuntu server 15 (LAMP and only eth0).

/etc/iproute2/rt_tables

```
    1   tunnel0
```

I PREPARE THE ROUTES AND MARKS

```
ip route add 0.0.0.0/0 dev tun0 table 1
ip rule add from all fwmark 1 table 1
ip route flush cache
```

(also tried to use table ID, to declare via "10.123.123.x" with the tun0 address and the tun0 gateway...)

IPTABLES

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -p tcp --dport 80 -j MARK --set-mark 1
iptables-save
```

I see the eth0 ISP public IP, instead of tun0, which I can see forcing a "route add" static route. What am I missing? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved and documented it here:
http://aftermanict.blogspot.it/2015/11/bash-iptables-iproute2-and-multiple.html

This will make the kernel permanently route packets, enables multiple routes and even for networks not attested on the machine:

```
nano /etc/sysctl.conf

net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 2
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 2
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

for f in /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*/rp_filter; do echo 0 >| $f ; done
```

This will initialize iptables and in particular mangle and nat, which are needed for marking the traffic:

```
iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -X
```

add the alternative routes editing:

```
nano /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
```

Add (names are your references):

```
1 tunnel0
2 tunnel1
```

add routes and rules, we use tables IDs instead of names which are more immediate. As you can notice, the gateway is irrelevant, especially for tunnels which can have dynamic gateways:

```
ip route add 0.0.0.0/0 dev tun0 table 1
ip route add 0.0.0.0/0 dev tun1 table 2
```

add rules to mark traffic and bind to the corresponding table:

```
ip rule add from all fwmark 1 table 1
ip rule add from all fwmark 2 table 2
ip route flush cache
```

check if you like:

```
ip route show table 1
ip route show table 2
ip rule show
```

if you miss something, you can delete this way:

```
ip rule del table 1
ip route flush table 1
```

NOW THE MISSING PART:
THIS WONT WORK:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -p tcp --dport 80 -j MARK --set-mark 1
```

THIS WILL:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -t mangle -p tcp --dport 80 -j MARK --set-mark 1
iptables-save
```

Do you need to select traffic and push it simultaneously in a device / tunnel? No problem, I solved this too:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -t mangle -p tcp --dport 10001 -j MARK --set-mark 1
iptables -A OUTPUT -t mangle -p tcp --dport 10002 -j MARK --set-mark 2
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 10001 -j DNAT --to :80
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 10002 -j DNAT --to :80
```

NAT mandatory for reply

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $DEV1 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $DEV2 -j MASQUERADE

iptables-save
```

Comment: Link-only answers aren't useful nor appreciated here (even when answering your own question). Please provide content *here* and link elsewhere for more details if necessary.

Comment: Posted the full solution for user convenience

Comment: Thank you. FYI it's not only for convenience, but also to ensure that your answer remains helpful for future readers, even after your blog disappears.

Comment: THIS WORKED!

It was the natting that totally messed me around!

Comment: @Enjoy87 you can be grateful by rating my solution with 1 click :-)

Comment: I got mine working with PREROUTING (which this answer says doesn't work)... I'm not sure why my case is different.

Answer (score -1):

I tried the above solution but it didn't have an effect for me.  For some reason the traffic always follows the default route in the main routing table.

```
iptables -t mangle -nvL
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 428 packets, 35952 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  428 35952 MARK      !tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0           !172.20.50.0/24       MARK set 0x11
```

As you see the packet count is increasing so the prerouting rule is being applied

```
ip rule ls
0:  from all lookup local
100:    from all fwmark 0x11 lookup table1
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

Here are my table rules

```
ip route show table table1
default via 172.20.50.2 dev eth0
```

At this point there are no ping replies going out of eth0
However, when exec this command to the main routing table

```
ip route add default via 172.20.50.2 dev eth0
```

Now the ping replies go through with no problem.